# Menu dropdown is not showing

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have integrated the `yoo_pace` theme of `YOOTHEME` in a site which joomla version is 2.5.6. To show submenu items I have made all the require changes to the main menu module, like show submenu to yes, start level 1 and end level all. Inspite of all the changes, the submenu items are still not coming when I hover a menu which has its child items. Please give a solution.

Comment: can you please provide a link to your site? You should actually post on the Yootheme forum as support is provided for the price you pay for the template subscription. On a side not, you should upgrade to Joomla 2.5.11

Comment: http://tischerhomeinspection.com. In the left column services has its child items.

Comment: well you have done some major major changes to the template. There aren't any errors in the console, but it might be due to the fact you have been editing the code for the menu. I still think you should post on the Yootheme Forum as they are there to help if you have bought one of their templates

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with another yootheme. Submenus did not show on hover.

What fixed it for me:

Go to the Module Manager, edit your menu module.

In the Details section of the module, the first 3 items are:

- Title
- Show Title Yes/No
- Position

Changing the value of 'Position' fixed this for my setup. This value determines in what template position your menu module will be shown. In my case this value was set to 'menu'.

The dropdown list shows Template names, and below each template name a number of position items. The value 'menu' in various form showed up several times in my case, for example as a position of the Yootheme template, but also as a position at the bottom of the list, below the heading 'Custom Position'. In my case the value was set to Custom Position -> menu.

I changed this value, by going through the list and going to the positions listed under the Yootheme template. This showed a value called 'Menu [menu]' . I selected this value, saved the module settings, reloaded the page with the menu and submenu's showed up on hover!